# Problems while scraping a table from a website?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am working in extracting the table from this site. Although I matched the xpaths and spotted the fields of the table, I'm not able to extract any content from the site, this is how my spider looks like:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from table.items import TableItem


class Table(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "table1"
    start_urls = (
        'wesite.com',
    )
    #//div[4]//div[1]//div[1]//table[1]
    #
    def parse(self, response):
        sites = response.xpath('//*[@id="tabs-1"]/table//tr')[1:-2]
        print('\n***********************************\n',sites)

        for site in sites:
            item = TableItem()
            item['col1'] = site.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract()
            item['col2'] = site.xpath('td[2]/text()').extract()
            yield item
            print('\n**********\n',item)
```

I guess that my main problem is this line:

```
sites = response.xpath('//*[@id="tabs-1"]/table[1]/tr')
```

I actually can retrive the content. However, it has an very large repeated incorrect format (it is malformed). Any idea of how to get the table?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes browsers add their own DOM elements while rendering. For your given site, the right xpath selector is `response.xpath('//*[@id="tabs-1"]/table//tr')` to find table rows.

Edited: Added code to fetch the right elements from the table

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from table.items import TableItem


class Table(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "table1"
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/drugshortages/default.cfm#tabs-1',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        sites = response.xpath('//*[@id="tabs-1"]/table//tr')

        for site in sites:
            item = TableItem()
            item['col1'] = site.xpath('td/a/text()').extract_first()
            col2 = site.xpath('td/em/strong/text()')
            if col2:
                item['col2'] = site.xpath('td/em/strong/text()')[0].extract().strip()
            else:
                item['col2'] = 'Not Available'
            yield item
```

Comment: I am looking into it too. Give me 2 mins

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect the code you need to fetch the data

Comment: what do you see when you print `item['col1']` ?

Comment: oh. I have replaced `extract()` with `extract_first()` in the answer.

Comment: Thanks!, apperantly.. I am getting several `\n` in `col2` any idea of how to remove them?.

Comment: Updated the answer to check if the `col2` exists else `item['col2']` is set to `Not Available`.

Comment: Thanks!.... finally how do you recommend me to extract xpaths?.... I tried with firebug.. is there any other tool?...

Comment: Firebug is good. Try to use [scrapy shell](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html) first before writing your spiders to check if the xpath will fetch the data you need. You can run the command `scrapy shell http://google.com` to start debugging the xpaths